# Creating instance of a class dynamically

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to create and use an instance of a class dynamically but keep running into the error " a is a variable but used as a type".

```
  //First we need to find the project that holds all of our entity models in the assembly
        var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                      .Where(x => x.FullName.Contains("MyProject.Models"))
                      .FirstOrDefault();

 //Now we need to search through the assembly to match the Entity to the supplied TableName
        var type = assembly.GetTypes()
                  .FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == localTableName);

        var a = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Why can't I use this like so

```
List<a> dynamicList = new List<a>;
```

or what I need to do this

```
var query = context.Database.SqlQuery<a>(...);
```

In that duplicate that you have linked it just translates a list. I may not need a list I may need the class to use in a SQLQuery

Comment: You're missing come code there in the Declaration

Comment: Im not great in C# but.. it should be more like.. "  = new  List<typeof(a)>"

Comment: If "a" is a type than do not name variable "a". Change `var a ...` to `var b ...` and it should be ok. It seems that you have name duplication variable vs class.

Comment: `a` is not a `Type`.  It is an instance of that type.  You will need to follow the duplicate and use `type` as the generic parameter.

Comment: @PablonotPicasso  No pablo a is not the type it just a variable name. The type is a instance of my Class named "MYCLASS" a is a variable that represents that class

Comment: @TerranceJackson No, `type` is a variable containing the runtime type information for your class.  `a` contains an instance of that class.

Comment: @Amy so why am I unable to use that class in the context of var query = context.Database.SqlQuery<a>(...)

Comment: @TerranceJackson Because you can't use *runtime* type information at *compile* time.  Also, `SqlQuery<a>` won't work for another reason, because, again, `a` is not a variable containing runtime type information.  `type` is that variable.  `a` is an instance of your class.